# gettext is not changing the language after upgrading to wamp 3

Tags: php, windows, apache, wamp, gettext

I have a php project that uses the gettext functionality to translate the texts. I have two languages in my project, Spanish and English.

The language file structure is the next:

```
/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/plantasenelaire.mo
/locale/es_ES/LC_MESSAGES/plantasenelaire.mo
```

The php code that I am using to select one language or another is the next:

```
if($languageCode == "en")
    {
        $languageEncode = "en_US";
    }
elseif($languageCode == "es")
    {
        $languageEncode = "es_ES";
    }
    else
    {
        $languageEncode = "en_US";
    }

putenv("LC_ALL=$languageEncode");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $languageEncode);

bindtextdomain("plantasenelaire", "./locale/");
textdomain("plantasenelaire");
bind_textdomain_codeset("plantasenelaire", 'UTF-8');
```

The code works just fine when using wamp 2.4 (32bits) with Apache 2.4.4 and PHP 5.4.16 on my Windows 7 64 bits.

The code also works fine on my linux shared hosting when using PHP 5.6 or PHP 7

Today I decided uninstall my wamp 2.4 and upgrade to wamp 3 with Apache 2.4.23 – PHP 5.6.25/7.0.10. I have installed all the Visual C++ Packages needed and then installed wamp 3 64 bits.

The code works but the language is always in Spanish no matter what I do. Always Spanish no matter if I use PHP 5.6 or 7.

I have tried multiples combinations and codes for the putenv and setlocale functions that I have found on the Internet without any luck :/

After trying wamp 3 (32 and 64 version) I went back to wamp 2.4, just to check if any of the Visual C++ Packages I installed messed up something on my Windows...

Everything works fine on wamp 2.4 with Apache 2.4.4 and PHP 5.4.16. It also works fine in my hosting as I said with PHP 5.6 and 7.

I really don't know what else to try.

Anyone can help me here? Any suggestion is welcomed.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Did you find a solve ? Nobody find a workaround for wamp 64

Comment: Hi @Reign.85, yes I ended up having two different mo files in my /locale/es_ES/LC_MESSAGES directory: es.mo and en.mo.

I load one file or another depending of the language:

    putenv("LC_ALL=es_ES");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");

    bindtextdomain($languageCode, "./locale/");
    textdomain($languageCode);
    bind_textdomain_codeset($languageCode, 'UTF-8');

I hope that helps you